# How to Get button text using onclicklistener in Android Java?

Tags: android, android-button

I have mutliple buttons in my app, i want to get button text and need to append that selected button text along with the URL stored in String. How to get button text and append it with String URL after the `search/label/`...?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String link = "www.abc.com/search/label/";

public void button1(View View){
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: you can get the string using view.getText().toString()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getText()`:

```
Uri.parse(link + button.getText());
```

Just implement an OnClickListener wherever you want and set it your  button(s) by invoking `setOnClickListener()`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == button1) {
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(link + ((Button) view).getText()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Or to identify button with id, you can use `getId` to compare.

```
if (view.getId = R.id.button1)
```

Comment: Have so many buttons, how do i call this with onclicklistener?

Answer (score 0):

So when you click any button, say you have 2 buttons

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonOne;
private Button buttonTwo;
String link = "www.abc.com/search/label/";


buttonOne = findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonTwo = findViewById(R.id.button2);


//set the listener to as much buttons as you need
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
.....

@override
public void onClick(View view){

Button button = (Button)view;
button.setText(link + button.getText());

}


 }
```

Comment: is there any other way to do this quickly, like in javascript we define classes and select from all buttons with class?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout for all the Button's add android:onClick="onButtonClicked" as:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:onClick="onButtonClicked"/>
```

Then in your activity:

```
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    Button button = (Button)view;
    String buttonText = button.getText().toString();


    //if you want to detect the different buttons...
    //else no need to use the switch
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            //do something button1 clicked
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            //do something button2 clicked
            break;
    }
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(link + buttonText));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```